# FFMPEG Oddities when decoding

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

Here's my decoding code:

http://pastebin.ca/2120920

I can successfully decode H264 video's, and some AVI's. My problem is that it's not very stable, it doesn't decode most formats yet it works with others, is this a problem with damaged headers or maybe missing information in the video data? How can I make this decoder code more effective?

Comment: FFmpeg comes with a simple SDL-based video player called ffplay. Test your files against ffplay to verify that FFmpeg's libraries can handle them in the first place. If ffplay works, then we can start looking at how ffplay's API usage differs from your code.

Comment: For some funny reason I couldn't build ffplay.exe even with --enable--ffplay, but I've downloaded it pre-built and it runs all my files. I'm going to look at ffplay.c for starters.

Comment: What platform are you on? Do you have the SDL dev files installed?

Comment: It's for work and unfortunately I'm on Windows, I tried earlier to build ffplay.c with SDL, but I had undefined references to a a few functions. Didn't tinker with it too long. I've built ffmpeg using MinGW and Msys btw.

Comment: many times you have to build libavcodec with extra parameters, like --enable-XXX maybe?